# Serialize CvKNearest class using Boost Serialization library

Tags: c++, boost, opencv, boost-serialization

Is there a simple way to save a KNN classifier in OpenCV by using the C++ API?

I have tried to save a KNN classifier described [here](http://www.functionx.com/cpp/articles/serialization.htm) after wrapping CvKNearest class inside another class.

It successfully saves to disk, but when I read from it running *predict* method gives me **segmentation fault** (core dumped) error.

My wrapper class is as follows:

```
class KNNWrapper
{
    CvKNearest knn;
    bool train(Mat& traindata, Mat& trainclasses)
    {

    }
    void test(Mat& testdata, Mat& testclasses)
    {

    }
}
```

I've heard that Boost Serialization library is more robust and safe. Can anyone point me to proper resources where I can get this done with Boost library?

Comment: Which Operating System? 32bit, 64bit? Which OpenCV Version? Saving and loading is no problem with the OpenCV Machine Learning library. Do you have a full code listing with your data? The wrapper there is not really meaningful.

Comment: I'm using a 64 bit Ubuntu, OpenCV 2.3.1. I'm looking to save and load a KNN classifier. I have the following code over here https://gist.github.com/3008331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tisch is totally right and I'd like to correct myself. The [CvKNearest](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html) doesn't override the [load](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#cvstatmodel-load) and [save](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#cvstatmodel-save) functions of the [CVStatModel](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#cvstatmodel).

But since a [CvKNearest](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html) doesn't compute a model, there's no internal state to store. Of course, you want to store the training and test `cv::Mat` data you have passed. You can use the [FileStorage](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html#FileStorage%3a%3aFileStorage%28%29) class for this, a great description and tutorial is given at:

- http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html

If you want to offer the same API as in the other statistical models in OpenCV (which makes sense) I suppose to subclass the [CvKNearest](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html) and offer a save and load function, which respectively serialize the training/test data and deserialize it by using the [FileStorage](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html#FileStorage%3a%3aFileStorage%28%29).

Comment: CvKNearest does not implement the necessary function from CvStatModel. So your solution is not possible.